# Dropdown changes its size when page size is changed

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a select element in my form. When i zoom in or zoom out my browser ,the select element gets resized and changes its position. Kindy help me out. I will attach the code also.

```
 <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" style="height:50px;" id="search_color">
          <option value=" " hidden>Color</option>
          <option value="0">Red</option>
          <option value="1">Green</option>
          <option value="2">Blue</option>
          <option value="3">Yellow</option>
          <option value="4">Orange</option>
          <option value="5">Purple</option>
          <option value="6">Grey</option>
          <option value="7">Multicolor</option>

        </select>
 </div>
```

Comment: what do you mean changes its position?

Comment: can you attach screenshot and what is your expected result

Comment: Initially, the dropdown is at the center of the page, when I zoom in or zoom out the page the dropdown is not at the center it moves to the corner of the page.

Comment: okay I will post my answer, I think you can use a basic center tag for that one because of the div class it changes the position of your select

Answer (score 0):

Basically, bootstrap classes have some behavior that varies depending on the size of the screen. In your case, You can actually apply a basic HTML `center tag` to override bootstrap class behavior and retain your `dropdown option` to the center of the screen.
Try this one:

```
<div class="form-group">
       <center>
       <select class="form-control" style="height:50px;" id="search_color">
          <option value=" " hidden>Color</option>
          <option value="0">Red</option>
          <option value="1">Green</option>
          <option value="2">Blue</option>
          <option value="3">Yellow</option>
          <option value="4">Orange</option>
          <option value="5">Purple</option>
          <option value="6">Grey</option>
          <option value="7">Multicolor</option>

        </select>
        </center> 
 </div>
```